# How to apply Lemmatization to a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lemmatization

If i had the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['challenging', 'swimming'], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Output
          col1  col2
0  challenging     3
1     swimming     4
```

I am using the WordNetLemmatizer:

```
print(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize('challenging',pos='v'))
print(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize('swimming',pos='v'))

Output
challenge
swim
```

How can I apply this lemmatization function to all elements of col1 from the original dataframe?

I have tried the following but no luck since it requires an input of pos so no change to dataframe

```
df['col1'] =df['col1'].apply(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize)
```

If i try:

```
df['col1'] =df['col1'].apply(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(pos='v'))
```

I get

> TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'

The desired output is:

```
        col1  col2
0       challenge     3
1       swim     4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `lambda` function inside the `apply` to pass the `word` argument.

```py
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda word: wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos='v'))
print(df)
```

```py
        col1  col2
0  challenge     3
1       swim     4
```

Answer (score 0):

For a best output, you can use spacy

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")  # load an existing English template
df['col1'] = [j.lemma_ for i in df['col1'] for j in nlp(i)]
```

You must install spacy, then install english langage

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the WordNetLemmatizer?

Comment: For spacy, this piece of code is the way to get the root of the word